# Carriage return on ajax-php response

Tags: php, ajax

I move my weapp to a new server with php 5.4.4. I have some troubles while getting response from ajax call, the response is prepend by a carriage return so my if stantement on the response are broke.
I found some related answers which tell to check the scripts for carriage return or white space near or after the php tags but I still have the problem.

The strange thing is that in on my local environment or my other old server with php 5.2.6 everything works perfect and the ajax responses are clean.

What I have to check? Maybe the file on the new server is with different charset or something like that?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you jump your local machine to PHP 5.4.4 to debug it?

Comment: Sorry I miss some infos. My coworker tried on local windows machine with php 5.5.12 and works fine. I tried with 5.4.3 and works. The only difference is windows/linux. But the old server is still linux. Is possible the is something related with the encoding of the files?

Comment: I would bet the other difference is `output_buffering` setting.

Comment: @Marek on localhost and on the new "notworking" server I have `4096`. On the old "workinG" server I have `no value`